# How to use Comet in a JSP Chat Application

Tags: jquery, ajax, comet

I am using Netbeans to create a Chat web application using Java EE, I use jquery function to connect to a Servlet, which Connects to Database to fetch some information, for example I managed to update a DIV with the list of Online users, each 5 seconds.

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
    $.get('MyServlet', {
            roomId: roomToJoin
        }, function (responseText) { 

    //Some codes Here
    //responseText is returned as a chain of user names
    //they get separated using JavaScript codes and then appended in a div

    });  //Update the list of Online users each 5 secondes

    },5000);
```

But doing the same technique to update the messages written by the users is kinda difficult, yet possible, but a more smart technique which I found during my search is the Comet technique, or reverse ajax, or long poling, and the only example I found is the Counter example, its all over the web, and I really didn't understand and it doesn't even meet my requirements, I don't know what's the good approach for this, I don't know if messages should be stored in the database and fetched again, I really don't know the codes to use Comet, I hope you can help me guys because this is the core of the Chat app, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

To build a web-based realtime chatroom is not an easy task. Especially it is hard to deal with Ajax/Comet technical issues. You can use message pushing cloud services such as [EZComet](http://ezcomet.com) (I'm the founder), [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) or [Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/). You can reference to a very simple chatroom example [here](http://ezcomet.com/demo/chatroom)

To receive messages on your javascript client, you can call the JS API like this. When there is new message received, your callback function will be called, and you can do corresponding reaction there, such as display a message, update user list

```
ez_comet.subscribe({
    user_name: 'demo', 
    channel: 'chatroom', 
    callback: callback,
    auto_tick: false,
    msg_type: 'json'
});
```

To submit a chatroom message, you can push a message to the channel via the API. The example in PHP

```
<?php

// Include ezcomet PHP SDK, it can be found here 
// https://ezcomet.com/tools/php_sdk
include 'ezcomet.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$msg = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'message' => $message
);

$tick = push_msg('your api key', 'demo', 'chatroom', @json_encode($msg));
echo "tick: $tick";

?>
```